# dialog not displayed properly if using different functions for both orientations

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

Well in onCreate method i have defined different function for both the orientations using

if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
{
   //some code
}else
{
   //some other code
}
and if one message is displayed in portrait mode then it gives problem when changed to landscape mode and vice-versa.
What can i do about it???

Comment: Problem is i need to display the same dialog in both the orientations and right now its not displaying properly.

Comment: Any screenshot ? "Not displaying properly" means pretty nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure you dismiss the current Dialog that is showing in `onDestroy` with `dismissDialog` - if you use the `showDialog` and `onCreateDialog` methods then Android automatically assumes you want the Dialog managed by the activity, which means it recreates the old dialog when rotate.

Comment: Ya but i need to display that dialog in both the orientations and right now its not displaying properly.